# Oracle Apex Currency format mask remove decimal

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am currently using the format mask FML999G999G999G999G990D00 to display this format: $123,456,666.00

However i need to remove the decimal part and only show comma separated dollar format, i.e. $123,456,666

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C). The format model is just a string that you can modify. In the one you are using, the 'D00' means "The Decimal character - `D`" followed by 2 trailing zeroes `00`. So if you remove the "D00" you'll end up with a value without decimals.

```
select to_char(
   100
  ,'FML999G999G999G999G990D00'
) with_decimals
      ,to_char(
   100
  ,'FML999G999G999G999G990'
) without_decimals
  from dual;

WITH_DECIMALS                     WITHOUT_DECIMALS              
--------------------------------- ------------------------------
$100.00                           $100
```